# Access on premises Jenkins from google cloud

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to implement dynamic slave provisioning on Jenkins by using Kubernetes Plugin. My Jenkins master is running on on-premise machine whereas the Kubernetes cluster is on Google cloud(GKE). After initial configuration as per plugin documentation I was able to see the agent PODS on GKE Cluster but not in running state. PODS are getting exited as they are not able to reach the Jenkins URL (which is on-premises). Has any one tried implementing such scenario? If yes then help would be much appreciated. I am not getting any clue how to get this implemented.

If it is not feasible then I have to look for GCE plugin which will provision VM's as agents.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm going to assume that your issue is just establishing a network path between your GKE cluster and your on-prem Jenkins URL. I think you've got at least three options: 1) get your IT team to open up the firewall to access Jenkins through a public URL from the cloud, 2) get a site-to-site VPN between your Jenkins machine and GCE to access Jenkins through a private URL from the cloud, or 3) set up an SSH reverse tunnel outbound from your Jenkins machine to a GCE instance to expose the Jenkins service to access from the cloud without having to set up an inbound path to the on-prem server.